# Symfony2 on WAMP server is not working

Tags: php, symfony, wampserver

I have installed WAMP server with following details

```
1. Apache httpd 2.2.22
2. PHP 5.4.3
3. MySQL 5.5.24
```

I want to run Symfony2 on this so I downloded this

```
Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.2.1
```

And tried to make application from it

I am getting following error for it

```
    1/1 InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "framework" (in D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\app/config/config_dev.yml). Looked for namespace "framework", found "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "jms_aop", "jms_di_extra", "jms_security_extra", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"

        in D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader.php line 268
        at YamlFileLoader->validate(array('imports' => array(array('resource' => 'config.yml')), 'framework' => array('router' => array('resource' => '%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml'), 'profiler' => array('only_exceptions' => false)), 'web_profiler' => array('toolbar'
=> true, 'intercept_redirects' => false), 'monolog' => array('handlers' => array('main' => array('type' => 'stream', 'path'
=> '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log', 'level' => 'debug'), 'firephp' => array('type' => 'firephp', 'level' => 'info'), 'chromephp' => array('type' => 'chromephp', 'level' => 'info'))), 'assetic' => array('use_controller' => true)), 'D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\app/config/config_dev.yml') in D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader.php line 238
        at YamlFileLoader->loadFile('D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\app/config/config_dev.yml') in D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader.php line 42
        at YamlFileLoader->load('D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\app/config/config_dev.yml', null) in D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\DelegatingLoader.php line 52
        at DelegatingLoader->load('D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\app/config/config_dev.yml') in D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php line 36
        at AppKernel->registerContainerConfiguration(object(DelegatingLoader)) in D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 653
        at Kernel->buildContainer() in D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 593
        at Kernel->initializeContainer() in D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 378
        at Kernel->boot() in D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 409
        at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in D:\Program files\wamp\www\Symfony\web\app_dev.php line 26
```

Not able to understand, how solve this problem ?

or where is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error is usually thrown if you forgot to register a bundle and have already put bundle-specific configurations into **app/config/config.yml**.

The 'framework' configuration namespace is provided by the FrameworkBundle.

Please make sure you have FrameworkBundle registered in your **app/AppKernel.php**

```
<?php

[...]

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            [...]
```

Please also clear your cache with **app/console cache:clear** ( probably not working aswell ) or remove the contents of app/cache folder manually.

Comment: app/Resources/config/config.yml  i think it is app/config/config.yml and config_dev.yml or config_test.yml , these all are there

Comment: updated my answer to the correct location. This error is thrown because there is a framework: configuration in config.yml. for every root-level configuration/namespace ... there has to be an extension being able to load them ( provided by a bundle ). If the bundle is not registered in the kernel it cant load the configuration ... even if the files are physically on your hard drive. >>>> Did you check FrameworkBundle is registered in AppKernel.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran `check.php`, `config.php` as nicely described in the `README.md`? I would also recommend to use Symfony with composer, instead of with vendors. Please check [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html) for a proper setup.